# Box OAuth 2 login page: is there a mobile alternative?

Tags: box-api

We've implemented Box's OAuth 2 authentication for our iPad app, and we present it to the user in a webview whose dimensions are 528px x 540px.

The authentication page provided from Box is always a much larger width, though. This forces the user to scroll far to the right to see where they actually log in.

Is there any way to force a mobile (i.e. iphone) login page?

We have previously tried to use the `m.box.com` URL in the OAuth process. The only difference is that it doubles up the box logo, like in the following image:

[image: http://aplot.com/stackdir/box_auth.png]

Other people have mentioned this problem on Stack Overflow (at least, [tangentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838221/authentication-with-box-on-ipad)), but there was no answer available. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried the OAuth2 flow outlined in Box's documentation with https://m.box.com in place of https://www.box.com?

Comment: Hi, PB. Thanks for responding. Yes, we've tried using the m.box.com url. The only difference that makes is it strangely doubles up the box logo, but it still returns the desktop page. I will upload an image to show you how this appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OAuth page currently isn't optimized for mobile pages, but we're working on making it responsive.